# How can I pass variables to a mutateAsync?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm using `tanstackreact-query` and i'm having issues passing variables to a useMutation `fn`.

Query

```
export const useSaleData = {
  listAll: () => {
    return useQuery<any, any>({
      queryKey: ['fetchAllSales'],
      queryFn: saleServices.fetchAll,
    });
  },
  create: () => {
    return useMutation<any, any>({
      mutationKey: ['createSale'],
      mutationFn: async ({ customerId, saleDetail }: any) => {
        return await saleServices.create({
          customerId,
          saleDetail,
        });
      },
    });
  },
};
```

Component

```
const { data: createSaleData, mutateAsync: mutateSale } =
        useSaleData.create();

const onCreateSale = async () => {
   const sale = await mutateSale({
      customerId: customer.id,
      salesDetail: orderList,
    });
 };
```

Error
`Argument of type '{ customerId: any; saleDetail: any[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.`

I've read documentation and it says that `mutate` receives the first parameter as variables. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass type parameters to useMutation like so:

`useMutation<any, any>`

you're opting out of type inference. But useMutation has 4 type parameters, so the other two get their defaults assigned. One of them is TVariables, and that defaults to void.

So bottom line: get rid of the angle brackets `<>` and use type inference

Answer (score 0):

Look at bellow solution,

1.First you should defining the `useMutation` hook like this,

```
 const { mutateAsync: mutateSale } = useMutation<any, any>(
  ['createSale'], 
  ({ customerId, salesDetail }) => {
    return saleServices.create({
      customerId: customerId,
      saleDetail: salesDetail, // Try to pass correct variable name
    }).then(result => {
      return result;
    }).catch(error => {
      // Handle errors if you want to 
      console.error("Error:", error);
      throw error; // throw error
    });
  }
);
```

Look at above , we are using the `useMutation` hook to define a mutation operation. The `mutationKey` is an array `['createSale']`, which identifies this mutation operation.

The `mutationFn` is an asynchronous function that receives an object with properties `customerId` and `salesDetail` (note the corrected variable name). Inside `mutationFn`, you should perform the actual mutation (in this case, calling `saleServices.create`) and return the result.

2.After you should change your **onCreate** like bellow,

```
   const onCreateSale = () => {
  mutateSale({
    customerId: customer.id,
    saleDetail: orderList, // Corrected property name
  } as { customerId: any; saleDetail: any[] }) // Specify the expected parameter type
  .then(sale => {
    console.log('Sale created:', sale);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error creating sale:', error);
  });
};
```

Look at now, `mutateSale` is the `mutateAsync` function provided by `useMutation`. We call it with an object containing the **required** variables: `customerId` and `salesDetail`.

These variables are passed to the `mutationFn` we defined earlier.

The **try-catch** block is used to handle any errors that might occur during the mutation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: check now with new updated code with restart ide

Comment: Still prompts the same error

Comment: Again updated with then keyword

Comment: Still same error. The error happens when I pass parameters to the mutateSale `fn`.

Comment: Look at new update and try it

Comment: Nothing. With all due respect, please if you're not sure, stop guessing. It's in the mutate firm not the content.

Comment: Sorry for get your time and I'm update with Specify with that expected parameter types it my all so If you like you can try it

Comment: Nothing, but thanks!